# Laravel PUT/PATCH returns 302 Found and redirects to frontend URL

Tags: laravel, request, nuxt.js

1.) Having a Laravel route inside api.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'images'], function() {
        Route::put('/{image}', [\App\Http\Controllers\ImagesController::class, 'update']);
    });
});
```

Update method code:

```
public function update(Image $image, ImageData $data) {
    $image->update([
        'title' => $data->title,
        'source' => $data->source
    ]);
    return response('', 200);
}
```

2.) Nuxt:

```
export const useApiFetch = async <T>(request, opts?) => {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()
    return useFetch<T>(request, {baseURL: config.public.apiBase, ...opts})
}
```

Component

```
const finishEditing = async () => {
    await useApiFetch(`admin/images/${image.id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        data: props.image
    })
    store.editingTitle = false
    store.editingSource = false
}
```

When sending PUT or PATCH request, it returns `302 Found` and redirects to localhost:3000, which is the address for frontend. Why does this happens? Middleware setup for api routes is out-of-the-box.

Comment: And could you add the code for the update method from your ImageController

Comment: @OMiShah Sure! It is quite small, and debugger show that this redirect is happening before this method. By the way, middleware for api routes is as-out-of-the-box

Comment: Did you check whether this is a JS problem or a Laravel problem? What did you try to resolve it?

Comment: @NicoHaase I've had this problem previously when working with vanilla Vue on other project. Cannot recall what i did with this previously, i think i just used POST to send this data, because i didn't found any solution, so i decided to ask here. This problem appears only on PUT/PATCH routes, POST works correctly.

Comment: If the route is in api.php, then the route would be `/api/admin/images/{id}`

Comment: This problem 100% causes by Laravel, JS correctly sends the PATCH, then receives 302 from Laravel, then sends data to frontend URL

Comment: @aynber Yes, the query URL is correct, it is setting in composable useApiFetch, public.apiBase is http://(some-local-name)/api

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Usually, HTTP codes are send by the server, so I doubt that the JS code is really relevant her

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met similar issue before and it happens when the request is not authenticated.  You need to check your request is sent to controller correctly.

Maybe your request would be cut off in the middleware or something else like csrf.